# Logstash filtering, unable to parse .CSV with JSON data in it

Tags: json, csv, filter, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am new to Logstash and am trying to parse a CSV file, that also contains fields with JSON data (nested in some lines as well ). I am running into trouble with the CSV parsing as the JSON data contains commas and quotations.

```
filter {
  csv {
    separator => ","
    columns => [ "timestamp" , "timestamp_iso" , "log_level" , "tag" , "message" ]
    skip_empty_columns => true
    quote_char => "'"
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp_iso" , "yyyy'.'MM'.'dd HH:mm:ss'.'SSS"]
    target => "@timestamp"
  }
  mutate {
    convert => ["timestamp", "integer"]
    add_field => {
      "file" => "%{[@metadata][s3][key]}"
    }
  }
  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "message"
    skip_on_invalid_json => true
  }
  grok {
    match => { "file" => "%{GREEDYDATA:device_id}_%{GREEDYDATA:log_time}.csv" }
  }
}
```

The field I am looking to parse JSON data from is the Message field in the code above. The error message from logstash is:

```
 Error parsing csv {:field=>"message",......:exception=>#<CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1.>}
```

Any Help with this would be much appreciated

Comment: Perhaps you could use the dissect or grok filters instead of the csv filter